# How to define a method in build.gradle file, which can compile java files from a directory and copy some files

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I wish to define a method in build.gradle file, which will compile java files in a directory. And copy some files.

I wish to pass directory paths as parameters to this method.
So I can call this method from different tasks (each call having different directory paths).
Is that possible?

Comment: yes, but it might be painful. why do you want to do this? are your paths dynamic at runtime?

Comment: No paths are not dynamic. I want to perform 3 set of tasks, with just different directory paths. Currently, I have separate tasks for each directory path.
There is a lot of similar code in all these tasks.
So I was thinking if it could be possible to create a method which could help me avoid a lot of boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can write your own [compile task](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-write-a-simple-javacompile-task/6597/4).